# Python API Client Rerun function if run unsuccessfully

Tags: python, python-requests

Python Requests API client has a function that needs to re execute if run unsuccessfully.

```
Kitten(BaseClient):

    def create(self, **params):
        uri = self.BASE_URL
        data = dict(**(params or {}))
        r = self.client.post(uri, data=json.dumps(data))

        return r
```

If ran with

```
api = Kitten()
data = {"email": "bill@dow.com", "currency": "USD", "country": "US"  } 

r = api.create(**data)
```

The issue is whenever you run it, the first time it always returns back the request as GET, even when it it POST. The first time the post is sent, it returns back GET list of entries.

The later requests, second and later, api.create(**data) return back new entries created like they should be.

There is a status_code for get and post

```
# GET
r.status_code == 200

# POST
r.status_code == 201
```

What would be better Python way to re execute when status_code is 200, till a valid 201 is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know for sure that the 2nd post will always return your expected value, you can use a ternary operator to perform the check a second time:

```
Kitten(BaseClient):

    def create(self, **params):
        uri = self.BASE_URL
        data = dict(**(params or {}))
        r = self._get_response(uri, data)

        return r if r.status_code == 201 else self._get_response(uri, data)

    def _get_response(uri, data):
        return self.client.post(uri, data=json.dumps(data)
```

Otherwise you can put it in a while loop where the condition is that the status code == 201.

Comment: works for now, will keep in mind while loop for later